# Azure blob migration issue: no media attachment in themes items

Tags: azure, media-library

Recently, we did `Azure blob migration`.

- Installed package
- Ran scripts

Now media items are linked to an azure blob. Images are coming on the website on CM and CD. However, no themes are loading on the site.

While looking into the items under the themes folder, I found that no media attachment is visible there. (see the screenshot)

[image]

and in raw value, `[Blob Value]` is coming. (see the screenshot)

[image]

Could you please assist?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like during the migration item has been created but not attached. You can `re-attach` them from downloading from your other instance and try with the following steps.

1. Download the file from another working instance by clicking the `Download` link on the media item.
2. Go to the new Sitecore instance in the Media Library, locate the existing media file you want to replace, and click on it.
3. Under the `Media` section, Click `Attach` and you will be prompted to browse your computer for the new file.
4. Once you locate the file, click on it then choose `Open` and click on the `Attach` button.
5. The page will refresh and you’ll see the new file you attached.
6. Save your changes and publish them.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did this yesterday but then I have perform these steps to prod to afterwards.

Comment: Yes, you need to follow the same steps in all instances.